# Preposition used with "clock" and "watch"

Tags: prepositions

> It's 4 am __ the clock.
>   It's 4 am __ my watch.

Which preposition is to be used?

Comment: What makes you think a preposition fits in those sentences? I might say something like, "My watch says it's 4 am," but I can't think of any preposition I would use in your first sentence.

Comment: @jr **It's 4 by the kitchen clock** is a perfectly acceptable though perhaps old fashioned usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is **by**.

For example,

> [Let me see, — **what is the time by my watch**, for that baker's clock is certainly wrong?](https://books.google.com/books?id=ezIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22by%20my%20watch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil_8-9ybDbAhXLtlkKHWVdBjU4ChDoAQgoMAA)
>
> [...the sun began to rise once again just past midnight by my watch!](https://books.google.com/books?id=J-oZiHKkVwYC&pg=PA15&dq=%22by%20my%20watch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil_8-9ybDbAhXLtlkKHWVdBjU4ChDoAQhNMAc)
>
> [But it is three o'clock by my watch. I am sure I made an appointment for three o'clock, did I not?](https://books.google.com/books?id=SjGSAAAAIAAJ&q=%22by%20my%20watch%22&dq=%22by%20my%20watch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie0v75ybDbAhWvwFkKHctaC2EQ6AEIMzAC)

Answer (score 1):

> Which preposition is to be used?

"according to".

> It's 4 am according to the clock.
>   It's 4 am according to my watch.

[More info](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/writing/grammar/parts_of_speech/prepositions.htm): "Simple prepositions consist of one word only ... Complex prepositions consist of more than one word."

Comment: +1 - "according to" was my first thought, too – although it might be worth noting that this phrasing may imply that the speaker is not 100% sure their timepiece is 100% accurate.